# Nested line-through in css

Tags: html, css, text-decorations, strikethrough, line-through

In my scenario, I have sections of text with deleted sections, visualized by `line-through`. Sometimes, these sections are nested. I would like to produce an output like this (please run snippet):

```css
span.strike1 {
  text-decoration:line-through;
  text-decoration-style:solid;
}

span.strike2 {
  text-decoration:line-through;
  text-decoration-style:double;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. <span class="strike1">Aenean commodo ligula
eget dolor. </span><span class="strike2">Aenean massa.
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
sem.</span><span class="strike1"> Nulla consequat
massa quis enim.</span> Donec pede justo, fringilla
vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
```

However, I would like to reproduce the same result with nested elements. Without applying javascript, is this actually achievable? Nesting `text-decoration-style:double` into `text-decoration-style:solid` will produce a triple line (double + solid), see here:

```css
span.strike {
  text-decoration:line-through;
  text-decoration-style:solid;
}

span.strike span.strike {
  text-decoration:line-through;
  text-decoration-style:double;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. <span class="strike">Aenean commodo ligula eget
dolor. <span class="strike">Aenean massa. Cum sociis
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies
nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span> Nulla
consequat massa quis enim.</span> Donec pede justo,
fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
```

Further, it seems impossible to influence the position of `text-decoration`. I have also tried a workaround with `border` and `:after`, but this does not work with more than one line. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `background` `linear-gradient` painted via `currentcolor` to match text `color` instead `text-decoration`:

```css
p {
line-height:1.6em;
font-size:16px;
}
span.strike {background:linear-gradient(
to top, 
transparent 35%, 
currentcolor 35%, 
currentcolor calc(35% + 1px ) , 
transparent calc(35% + 1px ) 
);
}

span.strike span.strike {
background:linear-gradient(
to top, 
transparent 5px, 
currentcolor 5px, 
currentcolor 6px , 
white 6px, /* hide other bg */
white 9px,  /* hide other bg */
currentcolor 9px, 
currentcolor  10px, 
transparent 10px
);
}
/* why currentcolor ? , hover tripleed striked span */
span span:hover {
color:purple;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. <span class="strike">Aenean commodo ligula eget
dolor. <span class="strike">Aenean massa. Cum sociis
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies
nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span> Nulla
consequat massa quis enim.</span> Donec pede justo,
fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
```

> @BoltClock says : *This works provided the background is a solid color and you don't mind the less-than-precise "lines" ;)*

Comment: This works provided the background is a solid color and you don't mind the less-than-precise "lines" ;)

Comment: @BoltClock Yes,  It is a compromise than can be used if well understood, CSS has its limits ;)

Comment: Great. This works fine in my environment. Potentially, this also fixes other issues, like line-through conflicting with hyphens. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to prevent decorations from being drawn over descendant inline boxes (see [CSS2.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/text.html#decoration) and [css-text-decor-3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#line-decoration)). Your only recourse, if you don't want to (or can't) cheat by drawing fake decorations yourself, is splitting your outer `.strike` element at the boundaries of the inner `.strike` element in such a way as to produce a structure similar to your reference example.

Comment: Thanks - indeed I was thinking about splitting the `.strike` element, but this could produce other unforseen issues ... so I am trying to cover this with CSS, avoiding cheats as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution that works well in my case. I post it here as it might be of interest for others. While the background-gradient solution displayed excellently in browsers, it did not work well when printing the document. This solution separates the second strikethrough line from its text by surrounding it by another <span> element, which is moved a little upwards by scaling the font size. The font size is then reset in the nested span element to display the text correctly.

```css
p {
  line-height:1.5em;
}

span.strike {
  text-decoration:line-through;
  text-decoration-style:solid;
}

span.strikeLine {
  text-decoration:line-through;
  text-decoration-style:solid;
  font-size:1.43em;
  line-height:0;
}

span.strikeText {
  font-size:0.7em;
  line-height:1.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. <span class="strike">Aenean commodo ligula eget
dolor. <span class="strikeLine"><span class="strikeText">Aenean massa. Cum sociis
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies
nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span></span> Nulla
consequat massa quis enim.</span> Donec pede justo,
fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
```